# Maya 2016 crashes on quitting

Tags: crash, maya

I made a ui with pyside, and used in Maya 2016.
And at that time, I close the Maya window and it crashed.
I watched in script editor and I concluded that Maya tries to save all shelves but it fails.
It seems like executed in **muButtonCleanUp** function in "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2016\plug-ins\xgen\scripts\muAddShelfButton.mel".
Is this issue common? or do I have to be careful with creating pyside ui?

I get message when maya crashed

```
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name: maya.exe
Application Version: 16.6.2775.0
Application Timestamp: 56ec05d9
Fault Module Name: mayaHIK.dll
Fault Module Version: 16.6.2775.0 
Fault Module Timestamp: 56ec078c 
Exception Code: c000005 
Exception Offset: 000000000001abc6 
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
```

Comment: pyside ui won't make maya to crash normally, if you can share the code or minimal example that will be great. muButtonCleanUp is coming from xgen  so probably you can unload xgen and see what's happening then .

Comment: @Achayan It is not just a simple code and I can't find out *the statements*  that cause the problem. I am using QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsItem. And it creates and deletes the scenes and items continuously, does it makes the trouble?

Answer (score 0):

looks like mayaHIK is crashing?  Maybe try unloading that plugin to see if it helps.